# Uncaught ReferenceError: anOpen is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I copied the code from the tutorial for the datatables drill down tables, and I am getting this error. Datatable comes up just fine but when i click on the row it has the Uncaught ReferenceError: anOpen is not defined. I am not sure how to define it, and as what. It should display a row below the datatable row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable();

$('#table_id tbody tr').live('click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode;
    var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);

    if (i === -1) {
        $('img', this).attr('src', sImageUrl + "details_close.png");
        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details');
        anOpen.push(nTr);
    }
    else {
        $('img', this).attr('src', sImageUrl + "details_open.png");
        oTable.fnClose(nTr);
        anOpen.splice(i, 1);
    }
});

function fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr) {
    var oData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);
    var sOut =
'<div class="innerDetails">' +
  '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
    '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>' + oData.calldate + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>Browser:</td><td>' + oData.recordingfile + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>Platform:</td><td>' + oData.uniqueid + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>Version:</td><td>' + oData.clid + '</td></tr>' +
    '<tr><td>Grade:</td><td>' + oData.did + '</td></tr>' +
  '</table>' +
'</div>';
    return sOut;
}


$('#startdate').bind("change paste keyup", function () {
    var startdatetext = $('#startdate').val();
    startdatetext.replace("_", '');

    var startlength = startdatetext.length;
    console.log(startlength);

    if (startlength == 10 || startlength == 0) {
        $('#table_id').dataTable().fnDraw();
    }
});

$('#enddate').bind("change paste keyup", function () {
    var enddatetext = $('#enddate').val();
    enddatete = enddatetext.replace("_", '');

    var endlength = enddatetext.length;
    console.log(endlength);

    if (endlength == 10 || endlength == 0) {
        $('#table_id').dataTable().fnDraw();
    }
});

$('#csearchtext').bind("change paste keyup", function () {

    var input = $('#csearchtext').val();
    var dropdownindex = $("select[name='columnlist'] option:selected").index();
    var radioselected = $("input:radio[name='group2']:checked").val();
    var searchpattern = '';

    switch (radioselected) {
        case '1':
            searchpattern = '^' + input;
            break;
        case '2':
            searchpattern = input;
            break;
        case '3':
            searchpattern = input + '$';
            break;
    }

    $('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilter(searchpattern, dropdownindex + 1, true, true, true, false);

});

$('#columnlist').on('change', function () {

    $('#table_id').dataTable().fnFilterClear();

});

$('#dblist').on('change', function () {

    var selected = $('#dblist').find(":selected").text();
    tablefill(selected);

});

$('#search').click(function () {

    var selected = $('#dblist').find(":selected").text();
    tablefill(selected);

});

function tablefill(selected) {
    $('.advsearchbar').show();
    $('#stable').show();

    $('#table_id').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": '/php/connect/searchtablequery.php',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "db", "value": selected });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "calldate" },
            { "mData": "recordingfile" },
            { "mData": "uniqueid" },
            { "mData": "clid" },
            { "mData": "did" },
            { "mData": "lastapp" },
            { "mData": "dst" },
            { "mData": "disposition" },
            { "mData": "duration_in_mins_and_secs" }, ],
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<"H"Tfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/DataTables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf",
                {
                    "sExtends": "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons": ["csv", "xls", "pdf"]
                }]
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: `anOpen` is used for the first time on line 12 (including blank lines). However, unless this is defined somewhere above this script, the array is, as the error suggests, undefined. Also `.live()` is deprecated and removed as of ***jQuery 1.9***. You should consider modifying your code to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I changed it to on("click","tr"... at now nothing happens.

Comment: It should be something like the following: `$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) { ... });`. Try that and see if that works for you. The current selector goes all the way down to the row level. You want to delegate to the row however, so you'll stop searching the DOM at the body level.

Comment: It is working now, I just need to figure out the anOpen issue.

Comment: Try defining the array before you define `var oTable` like so: `var anOpen = [];` Let me know if this works and I'll write it all up in an answer for you.

Comment: The anOpen is suppose to be the array to check if the row is opened or closed. The tutorial is vague. http://datatables.net/blog/Drill-down_rows

Comment: Check [this](http://datatables.net/blog/Drill-down_rows#highlighter_613805) link. It takes you a little further down the page under the ***Table*** subheading. the first line under the `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` is `var anOpen = [];`.

Comment: I am finding it now, thank you. just post your first 2 responses and ill mark it as answer thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `anOpen` is used for the first time on line 12 (including blank lines). However, unless this is defined somewhere above this script, the array is, as the error suggests, undefined. You can fix this by modifying the code accordingly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var anOpen = []; // <- Add this line
    var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable();

    ...
});
```

This change can be found in the documentation [here](http://datatables.net/blog/Drill-down_rows#highlighter_613805) under the subheading ***Table***.

As a side note, .live() is deprecated and removed as of jQuery 1.9. You should consider modifying your code to use .on(). You can do that by modifying the `click` handler in the following way:

```
$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) { ... });
```

By modifying your code like so, you can delegate the `click` event for all `tr` elements within the table.

Hope this helps.